# Search query formation

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi I am using hibernate for my project . I need to form a query , its for search user purpose. in my user table i have logind,firstname,lastname,roleid,email etc. The user may enter only few details and then search. In this situation i need to form the hibernate query with the only fields that the users entered values.how can we implement this?

for example if the user enters loginid and firstname

then

select from User user where user.logind=1 and firstname like 'ABC'

please helpme out

Comment: i have already accepted few, not sure what i am doing wrong

Comment: You've actually never accepted an answer. Accepting is different than upvoting. To accept you click the checkbox icon next to an answer. This indicates that that answer was the best one/the one that actually solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate provides an Example API where you can use a partially filled object of what you're looking for to execute a query.  You can read more about it here:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-examples

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out Hibernate Criteria Queries.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objecstate-querying-criteria

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html